# Cannot access BlocProvider from initial screen on the new screen

Tags: flutter, bloc, flutter-bloc

I am using BlocProvider in my Flutter application to provide a bloc to the initial screen, `MyOffersListScreen`. However, when I navigate to a new screen, `NewOfferScreen`, using `Navigator.push`, I cannot access the same BlocProvider. How can I access the BlocProvider from the `NewOfferScreen`? Below is a simplified version of my code:

```dart
class MyOffersListScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider<MyOffersListBloc>(
      create: (context) => MyOffersListBloc(),
      child: Scaffold(
        // ...
      ),
    );
  }
}

class NewOfferScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Cannot access the MyOffersListBloc here
    // ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't know how you are navigating, but to access the same instance of the current block on the next screen, you must pass the block using `BlocProvider.value()`, so it will be in the context of the screen. Ex:

```
final _myOffersListBloc = context.read<MyOffersListBloc>();
Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => 
    BlocProvider.value(
      value: _myOffersListBloc,
      child: NewOfferScreen(),
)));
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. try declaring _myOffersListBloc and it doesn't find my BlocProvider when I navigate to the new screen, I am using my BlocProvider before Scaffold and navigate through floatingActionButton. `BlocProvider<MyOffersListBloc>(
        create: (context) => MyOffersListBloc(),
        child: Scaffold(....)` floatingActionButton: `floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(...`

Comment: try `final  _myOffersListBloc = BlocProvider.of< MyOffersListBloc >(context);` instead of `context.read`.